# Unknown extern method T System.Nullable`1::get_Value()

Tags: c#, android, dot42

I've run into a problem with my dot42 C# project:

```
Unknown extern method T System.Nullable`1::get_Value() at System.Void NokiaStyleProfiles.AddDialogue::btnAdd_Click(System.Object,System.EventArgs) (c:\Users\STO\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\NokiaStyleProfiles\NokiaStyleProfiles\AddDialogue.cs, position 86,13)
```

Code that's causing that problem:

```
int hourStart = timePickerStart.CurrentHour.Value; (timePicker.CurrentHour is an int?)
```

`(int)`, `.Value` and `.GetValueOrDefault()`, as expected, produce the same result : this error.

How can i fix it?

Comment: According to the API reference for [TimePicker](http://docs.dot42.com/Reference/T.Android.Widget.TimePicker) there is also an `int? GetCurrentHour()` method available. Have you tried that one as well?

Comment: That method too tries to convert int? to int, and that is what causes that error.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in `Version 1.0.0.67` for primitive types. The proposed workaround in the previous answer is no longer required. If you run check for updates it will update to the latest version of dot42.

*Disclosure: I work at dot42.*

Answer (score 0):

dot42 developer reply:

...

> Right now the Nullable type is not yet fully supported. This
>   feature is part of making struct's behave as actual struct's. For now
>   I recommend working around it.

...

Working workaround is:

```
int hourStart = Int32.Parse(timePickerStart.GetCurrentHour().ToString());
```

Comment: This is out of date now. Please consider updating or removing this answer.